# How to fit search tags and input onto same line of ui-select multiple select?

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

If you look at the [ui-select tutorial](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/#getting_started), and click on **Multiple Selection**, you see multiple selection dropdowns where once you select at least one, you get at least two "lines", which will contain the already selected entries, until the last line, in which you can search/select other entries in the dropdown.

[image]

Is there no way to put both the already selected entries and the search feature on the same line? That makes the most sense to me. Alternatively I'd be fine if there could be placeholder text where the "|" pipe is that says "enter text here" or something, but that seems impossible.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a `width: auto;` to the input, i see that it has a fixed with in the plnkr examples.

Sample [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DsMQ862NnbA0r2vorYVM)

Comment: Hi, did you try this on the plnkr? When I tried it, it didn't work. It makes sense that it wouldn't actually, because regardless of the width, the cursor can only be inserted into the last line.

Comment: yes, i've tried it in plnkr, i'll attach it to the answer

Comment: Where did you put the code? In the bottom of the CSS file?

Comment: Is there another place I can do so without putting it in the select.css file, which is part of the package that my project automatically updates and installs?

Comment: you can place it in any other css file that it's included after the `select.css` file

Comment: In your plnkr, once you move the mouse farther right on the dropdown, you can't click into the dropdown. Why is this? How can it be fixed?